# How to make all the list views scrollable at the same time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating app like the image shows. I am having issues with scrolling all the sections at the same time.

What I have done so far:

I have  added "journey search detail section and outbound section, and outboud results" in ONE listbuilder. `wrapContent` holds journey search detail section and outbound section

```dart
List<Widget> result = [];

final listOfFirstResults = new Expanded(
  child: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: (planets?.length ?? 0) + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return wrapContent;
      } else {
        return new JourneyResult(planets[index - 1]);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

I have added return detail section and return results in another list views. (this could be appended in the existing list view but i don't know how to do it).

```dart
final listOfSecondResults = new Expanded(
  child: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: (planets?.length ?? 0) + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return tripListSecondHeader;
      } else {
        return new JourneyResult(planets[index - 1]);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

I have added them in the list.

```dart
result.add(listOfFirstResults);
result.add(listOfSecondResults);
```

But I cannot make them scroll all at the same time.

```dart
return new Expanded(
  child: new Container(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[result[0], result[1]],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Wanted interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `SliverList` widget. It allows you to scroll multiple listviews at once.

Or perhaps I misunderstood the question and you want to scroll them in sync?

References:

- [Widget of the week on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM)
- [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question but if you want the 2 ListViews to scroll at the same time, just create a ScrollController and pass it as an argument to each ListView.